# Присваивание значений словарю

Tags: python, словари

Можно ли словарю присвоить сразу несколько значений по ключам?
Имеется в виду что-нибудь вроде:

```
 d = {'val1':0, 'val2':0, 'val3':0}

 d['val1', 'val2', 'val3'] = [1,2,3]
```

чтобы в результате было:

```
d.values() 
output: [1,2,3]
```

Я сейчас делаю так:

```
{key: val for key, val in zip(d.keys(),[1,2,3])}
```

То есть приходится создавать новый словарь, но мне бы хотелось переприсваивать некоторые значения в исходном словаре, скажем, 20 значений из 30 и писать 20 строк кода или создавать новый словарь для этого не хочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {}
keys, values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]
d.update(zip(keys, values))
d.values()

dict_values([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо большое!

Comment: Про update то я и забыл )

Comment: а я не дочитала до конца первую ссылку в гугле по словарям в питоне.( постараюсь быть внимательнее

Comment: Тут есть про сравнение по скорости различных способов, а также описывается возможность создания собственного класса для подобной операции: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222506/multiple-assignments-into-a-python-dictionary/21222526

Answer (score 0):

Да ну вроде и без особых ухищрений не сильно громоздко будет выглядеть через for и zip:

```
d = {'val1':0, 'val2':0, 'val3':0}
for k,v in zip(d, [1,2,3]):
  d[k] = v
print(d.values()) 

dict_values([1, 2, 3])
```

Хотя если вдруг есть вариант в одну строку, мне тоже интересно было бы посмотреть.

Примечание: в Python3 при итерировании словаря перебираются ключи.

Comment: Согласна, так делаю тоже, просто думала, что, вероятно, существует библиотека, где это реализовано в одну строку, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: zip(d,[1,2,3])
будет работать на 3м python

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'val1':0, 'val2':0, 'val3':0}
d = dict(zip(d.keys(), [1,2,3]))
```

Comment: хм, в этом случае либо все значения меняются, либо опять же создается новый словарь, при попытке модифицировать лишь некоторые значения, например: d = dict(zip([val1', 'val2'], [2,3])), будет словарь соответственно из двух элементов, а мне бы хотелось не модифицируемые значения оставлять в исходном словаре.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]